# Contact Us page script is not working

Tags: php, html

I have write code on my website contact us page but its not working.I check everything but still i am not receiving email when i try it my self.

I have this is Form:

```
<form id="contact-form"  class="cform" method="post">
          <label class="hide" 
                 for="author">
          Full Name
          </label>
          <input class="input-fields" id="full_name" name="full_name" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Full Name" value=""/>
          <label class="hide" for="email">Email</label>
          <input class="input-fields req-email" id="email" name="email" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Email Address" value=""/>
          <label class="hide" for="subject_title">Subject title</label>
          <input class="input-fields" id="subject_title" name="subject_title" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Subject Title" value=""/>
          <label class="hide" for="comment">Message</label>
          <textarea id="comment" class="input-fields form-control" required placeholder="Message" name="comment" cols="40" rows="200"></textarea>
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit-contact-info" class="contact-info-submit form-submit-button span2" value="Send message">
        </form>
```

And this is php:

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $to        = "mail@asrhouse.com"; // this is your Email address
     $from      = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
     $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
     $subject   = $_POST['subject_title'];
     $subject2  = "Copy of your form submission";
     $message   = $full_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['comment'];
     $message2  = "Here is a copy of your message " . $full_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['comment'];

 $headers   = "From:" . $from;
 $headers2  = "From:" . $to;
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
 $msgss= "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $full_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
 // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
   }
    ?>
```

Comment: What does it currently do? Are any errors thrown? Do you have a mail server setup?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: no error.it show me message "Mail Sent. Thank you ,'Sender name here' we will contact you shortly." ,But when i check my inbox there is not email receive.

Comment: because you're not checking for errors...where you will find that `$_POST['full_name']` does not match your input element's name. (wink)

Comment: I didn't check mail server setting but its on default setting .

Comment: but are you "displaying" them? `full_name != name`

Comment: @Fred-ii- ops ! let me check this also . :)

Comment: Plus, are you running the form AND PHP inside the same page or as 2 seperate pages?

Comment: You should check your spam or junk emails.

Comment: full name doesn't matter i think, because that is only in the body of the message. Check spam as Apul Gupta sad. Also try to `$a = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); var_dump($a)` Is it true or false?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i update my code still same no email receiving and i am using php + html on same page .

Comment: @ApulGupta ya i check everything but there is no email receiving.

Comment: I tested your code, with no problems. Make sure mail and PHP is indeed installed and running.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you but where php and mail should install ? my website is running online and i am changing from web hosting everything is fine but i don't know why email is not receiving on my domain email adress .

Comment: As I posted earlier up. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Add that and change `mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);` to `if(mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2)){ echo "Mail sent". } else { echo "Error".}` - Plus, mail might be sent to Spam or rejected. Your host may be blacklisted.

Comment: and `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);` to `if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){...}` same as above.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you .Let check with this .

Comment: You're welcome. Try out the answer below also. If that works, then your headers are not well-formed, but I'm not convinced that will change anything, but it's worth a shot. Error reporting and displaying them are your best bet. Plus, if you have access to mail logs, check those also.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you understand how you needs to format the email. You are missing vital header information in your emails. I am going to guess either your emails are going to SPAM since the method you are using will probably push it to SPAM without the proper headers. Or hopefully this format can help you figure it out. We cannot do much for you if no errors are present and we don't know the configuration of your box. Maybe it does not support PHP Mail function?

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: So what will this "drop-in" code with no explanation do any better?

Comment: It should help him understand how he needs to format the email. He is missing vital header information in his emails. I am going to guess either his emails are going to SPAM since the method he is using will probably push it to SPAM without the proper headers or the format presented to him may help him figure it out.

Comment: You should be writing that out in your answer instead.

Comment: You are right. Early start today ;) Just getting the coffee in! Done.